# Record and repeat message with IVR inputs in TaskRouter Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I am following a two-part tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMg5ytgyn1E for setting up TaskRouter.

I am able to successfully take the user input and direct them to respective teams on pressing the extension but my requirement is also to record a message from the caller when they press 0 and also repeat the IVR welcome message again when the caller presses #.

How can I integrate this with the current workflow presented in this tutorial?

Your help is appreciated!